# Max file size can recover on ext4

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

Is there a limitation for recovering big files on ext4 like ntfs ( 4 giga max )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use testdisk and photorec, it is capable of recovering the file you are able to store on that file system, as long as it doesn't exceed the file system limitation, for ext4, max file size will be 16TiB (for 4KB block file system).

Comment: wow, 16tera. thats really really huge... amazing. so I can make one container with 300Giga with no problems at all, right?

Comment: 300GiB is NOT a problem at all. What do you mean by container? dd and mount as loop device?

Comment: What do you mean by container? 'truecrypt container' one true crypt container 300g to put every thing on it, will be problem with that?

Comment: Gotcha, as long as TrueCrypt doesn't limit the size of a file container, it should be fine. The max file size is limited by the underlying filesystem.